# complex conjugate variables in a system of complex linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I was wondering how to solve a linear equation of the below type.

In the below equation, z=x+yi, a complex number.

$$(2+2i)z^*+(2-2i)z=10+(2-2i)(2+2i)$$

So, in the above equation, there are two unknown variables and only one equation. I have learned about normal con-Sylvester matrix equation, but they don't seem to fit this problem.

I understand that it could be like:
$$2*Re((2+2i)z^*)=10+(2-2i)(2+2i)$$

But the problem is how to find the value of x and y individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

I suggest that you write $z$ as $x + i y$ and then expand all products.

Afterwards, split the equations in two parts: the real part and the imaginary part. This will leave you with a system of two equations with two unknowns.

---

**Edit:** Just for the sake of completeness, and after [NIT_GUP](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/685313/nit-gup) solved the problem, here is the solution:

$$
(2+2i)z^∗ + (2−2i)z = 10 + (2−2i)(2+2i) \\
(2+2i)(x - i y) + (2−2i)(x + i y) = 10 + (2^2 + 2^2) \\
(2x \color{red}{+ 2ix} \color{blue}{- 2iy} + 2y) + (2x \color{red}{- 2ix} \color{blue}{+ 2iy} + 2y) = 18 \\
4x + 4y = 18 \\
x + y = \frac{9}{2}
$$

So, in this case we have a degenerate solution because the complex terms cancelled out in the equations above. In this case, the solution is a straight line in the complex plane with the equation:
$$
y = - x + \frac{9}{2} \ .
$$

[image: plot of the equation y = - x + 9/2]

Only after writing this I've noticed that [J. W. Tanner had already written a solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3276590).

Comment: I tried, it worked.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I added the solution in case somebody else finds a similar problem. If you think it's appropriate, you may accept one of the answers (there is a green button).

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=x+yi.$  The equation $(2+2i)z^*+(2-2i)z=10+(2-2i)(2+2i)=10+4+4=18$

then becomes $(2+2i)(x-yi)+(2-2i)(x+yi)$

$=(2x+2y+(2x-2y)i)+(2x+2y+(2y-2x)i)=4x+4y=18,$

so it is solved when $x+y=\dfrac{18}4=\dfrac9 2$.

There are infinitely many solutions.